# Removing single node from general tree in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, unix, tree, nodes

I have a simple general tree which is meant to mimic a simple Unix file management system, mimicing commands such as `touch`, `ls`, `cd`, `mkdir` and `rmdir`. The way I have it set up so far is by using a general Tree to mimic this system and then manipulating the nodes to have my desired effect with the aforementioned commands.

```
class TreeNode():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    
    def add_child(self, child):
        child.parent = child
        self.children.append(child)


    def remove_child(self):
        self.data = None
        self.children = None
        self.parent = None

def main():

    # initialising valid command list
    valid_commands = ["exit", "pwd" ,"cd", "ls", "mkdir", "rmdir", "touch"]

    # making the namespace through trees, initialising current directory to the root
    root = TreeNode("/")
    username = "root"
    global currentdirectory
    currentdirectory = root

    # making the list of all directories (cos not using classes)
    valid_drs = []

    # making the list of all files (cos not using classes)
    valid_files = []
    
    #function loop
    while True: #TO-DO: account for IndexError: list index out of range IF there are no more arguments
        raw_command = input("{}:{}$ ".format(username, currentdirectory.data))
        commandsplit = raw_command.split(" ")
        command = commandsplit[0]

        if command in valid_commands: # verifying if command can be found
            if command == "exit":
                print("bye, {}".format(username))
                exit()

            elif command == "pwd":
                pwd(currentdirectory)

            elif command == "cd":
                cd(commandsplit[1])

            elif command == "ls":
                ls(currentdirectory)
                print(valid_drs, valid_files)

            elif command == "mkdir":
                    try: 
                        valid_drs.append(mkdir(commandsplit[1], currentdirectory))
                    except IndexError:
                        print("usage: mkdir [-pv] [-m mode] directory_name ...")

            elif command == "rmdir":
                    try:
                        rmdir(commandsplit[1], currentdirectory)
                    except:
                        pass

            elif command == "touch":
                try:
                    valid_files.append(touch(commandsplit[1], currentdirectory))
                except IndexError:
                    print("usage: touch [-A [-][[hh]mm]SS] [-achm] [-r file] [-t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]] [-d YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:SS[.frac][tz]] file ...")
        else:
            cnf(command)


def pwd(directory):
    print(directory)


def cd(changeToDirectory):
    currentdirectory = changeToDirectory


def ls(directory):
    if len(directory.children) > 0:
        for child in directory.children:
            print(child.data)
    else:
        print(end='')


def mkdir(directoryname, currentdirectory):
    newDirectory = TreeNode(directoryname)
    currentdirectory.add_child(newDirectory)
    return newDirectory.data


def rmdir(directoryname, currentdirectory):
    #to-do


def touch(filename, currentdirectory):
    newFile = TreeNode(filename)
    currentdirectory.add_child(newFile)
    return newFile.data


def cnf(command):
    print("{}: Command not found".format(command))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've been trying to look online forever but I can't seem to find a way to implement rmdir - I don't know how I to "delete" the node. It's not all finished BTW

Thanks!

Comment: the `remove_child()` method just sets **all** values = `None`. This looks incorrect. Presumably you just want to delete the one child item ?

Comment: Yep! I just want to delete the one item